# Removing text from NSString between "@" and ":" while keeping the text after it

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, nsstring

So I'm reading the most recent tweet from a twitter bot and assigning it to a string, but sometimes it tweets directly to users. Here's an example of what that might look like.

```
NSString tweet = @("@user hey heres my message: BLah blah with symbols!");
//part I want to keep is: " BLah blah with symbols!"
//or it could end up being

NSString tweet = @("@otheruser my msg is: Wow heres some more blah: and a second colon");
//part I want to keep is: " Wow heres some more blah: and a second colon"
```

I want to always remove the first part that talks to the user, while keeping the message on the end. There are too many different messages to use "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString"

I don't want to use "exlude-replies" from the twitter API because this bot is very popular and that would require fetching up to 100 since "count" applies before

any idea how I could do this? I think it has something to do with regular expressions, but I haven't ever used them before or been able to get one working how I want. I would really appreciate the help from anyone whos comfortable with regex

edit: also if a regex won't work for this case, id accept an explanation of the limitation preventing that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution that I can think of is to create an NSMutable array, by using the NSString function `componentsSeparatedBy:@":"`, and simply remove the first element.

```
NSMutableArray *tweetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [tweet componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]];
[tweetArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Your issue with a colon appearing at random afterwards can be fixed by joining the pieces back together again.

```
tweet = [tweetArray componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
```

Edit: Fix an error pointed out by user 'maddy'

You'll have to stick this code in an if statement so that it does not execute in tweets that have a colon normally. You can use the fact that it always begins with @user however.

```
if ([tweet characterAtIndex:0] == '@' && [tweet characterAtIndex:1] != ' '){
    NSMutableArray *tweetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [tweet componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]];
    [tweetArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    tweet = [tweetArray componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
}
```

Comment: This won't work with a message such as "Please remove the : from this message".

Comment: @maddy, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I understand your comment now that you've edited it :P
But I admit, you're correct. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Cool i managed to get it working with this, thanks a lot for the help from both of you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
  NSString *myString = @"@username is me: by using this as sample text";
  NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@":"];
  NSString *newString= [myString substringFromIndex:range.location];
  NSLog(@"New String is : %@", newString);
```